# Duplicate net6 controller in mvc project never called

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, asp.net-core-6.0

I have a net6 solution which uses VueJS in a UI folder and has MVC controllers in an API project.

The project has been migrated from dotnet3.1 but works just fine.

I have tried copying one of the controller classes and duplicating it (with all appropriate renamings etc) to add another controller and its method endpoints.

This simply does not work - the browser request to that endpoint receives a 500 internal server error, but the endpoint method is never hit and none of the middleware even gets hit.

What’s going on? What obvious thing have I forgotten?

Here’s the original class and method head:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "MyRole")]
    public class FirstController : Controller
    {
        public FirstController()
        { }
 
        [Route("api/go/there"), HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GoThere()
        {
```

And here’s the duplicate:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "MyRole")]
    public class MyController : Controller
    {
        public MyController() { }
 
        [HttpGet, Route("api/do/it")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> doIt()
        {
```

Comment: Please share the details exception about the 500 error and the route config inside the program.cs